# How to change the size of shared system memory In Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I recently upgraded my laptop ram from 4gb ddr3 to 16gb ddr3.but my system shared memory is not increased so that i cannot increase my dedicated video ram more than 576mb.anyone help me to solve this problem guys please. i had a application that increases a system shared memory but after upgrading i reset my pc so i cannot remember the name of the application.i saw many video to increase my system shared memory.anyone help me guys please!!!.

My System Requirements :-

```
Model Name : Lenovo G50-80
MotherBoard : G50-80 MotherBoard
Ram : (2x8)16GB DDR3L 1600mhz
Graphics : Intel HD Graphics Family
Processor : Intel Core i3 4005U 1.70GHZ
```

Also,
There was no option to increase the size of the vram in my BIOS Settings As my bios version was old version B0CN95WW

Thanks For Reading to help me :)

[image]

Comment: Updating your firmware won't let you increase the amount of shared VRAM, most Intel iGPU around the time of your processor. had similar maximum limits as you have experienced.  You need different hardware if you need more than 512MB of VRAM. It does not matter if you have (8 GB, 16 GB, or 32 GB).  You won't be able to assign more than the maximum amount of VRAM.

Comment: You firmware upgrade wasn't a bad idea as there are cases where the limit WAS limited by BIOS/UEFI but @Ramhound is 100% on the mark (usually is).  If you are that worried about your VRAM, you probably should consider new hardware.  If you can't.. then you will need to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the
[Intel FAQ](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000020962/graphics.html),
the Intel HD Graphics 4400 can have up to 2048 MB of graphics memory.

Your image shows indeed :

```
Total Available Graphics Memory: 2624 MB
Dedicated Video Memory: 576 MB
System Video Memory: 0 MB
Shared System Memory: 2048 MB
```

Shared GPU memory is a type of *virtual memory*
(not physically allocated) that's typically used when your GPU
runs out of dedicated video memory.
In most cases the shared GPU memory will not be used at all.

You're probably looking into increasing the Dedicated Video Memory
(rather than the Shared System Memory), but that's only possible
in the BIOS. This option might be found in the BIOS section
"Advanced features" and may be called "Graphics Settings",
"VGA Share Memory Size", "Video Settings” or something similar.

If your BIOS does not have such an option, you're out of luck.

But if the reason you wish to increase the VRAM is because a game
is refusing to run, you may fake a larger VRAM by changing a
registry setting as follows:

- Run `regedit` and position to the following key:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel`.
- Right-click the Intel folder and choose *New > Key* and name
  it `GMM`.
- Click the new GMM folder on the left and right-click inside
  the right side.
- Select *New > DWORD (32-bit) Value* and name the new item
  `DedicatedSegmentSize` and give it a decimal value in megabytes.
- You will need to reboot after setting this value.

Comment: Faking the VRAM will allow the application start but the application won't perform at a level where it can actually be used.